Gack Ids in Data Cloud when try to create Sales Cloud data stream
STR:

Go to Data Streams.
Click new.
Select Salesforce CRM.
Obtain errors:
An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1585805846-1139967 (-1822086853)
Click on "All Objects".
Obtain additional error
We couldn't retrieve available objects for Pure Infusion Suites. Try again later. GackId: 1347125712-434496 (-884354614)

Why is happening and how can we overcome this?

When Data Cloud sandbox is refreshed from Production, default Sales Cloud connection is deactivated and must be manually activated or a new Sales cloud connection must be established before proceeding.

And when you select, you need to select Sandbox or activate production connection.
